# ASP.NET Core + resx - works only default culture

Tags: localization, asp.net-core

I am trying to port a WebForm app to MVC 6 and am having an issue with getting resources from a resx file. The code in the controller class returns only default resx values.

I tried both setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` & `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` as well as setting `Resources.MyResouces.Culture` to specific culture, but `Resources.MyResouces.Key` still returns only the default. What could be the problem?

```
public IActionResult MyAction(){
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
        Resources.test.Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");

    // The line below still returns the default English resource value
    var localizedValue = Resources.test.test_key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WebForms to Asp.Net Core is a pretty huge leap to take. I would recommend starting with the [Asp.Net Core localization sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/tree/dev/samples/LocalizationSample) on GitHub to get a clearer picture of how it works.

In particular, you may need to do some more configuration in your `Startup.cs` file.

Comment: Thank you. Actually it seems to be an issue with RC1. After upgrading to RC2 the same code works correctly.